# Does MVVMCross have a way to change the selector when clicking ImageButton on ListView?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, selector, mvvmcross

The problem is the same as not programming with MVVMCross, but I wonder if there is a "crossplatform" solution:

When using an ImageButton on a MvxBindableListView (or a ListView), we have to put some options in order to use an action on this button:

```
        <ImageButton
            ...
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="true" 
            ...
            local:MvxBind="'Click':{'Path':'Command1'}}"
          />
```

With these parameters, the buttons reacts on the "Command1". 
But the problem is that the "visual selector" of the ListView is not changing.

Let's give an example:

When you have 5 rows in your ListView, and the first one is selected.  I touch the ImageButton of the 3rd row, the "Command1" will react (with the 3rd Item of the ListView) but the selector will stay on the first row.

So, in Android, we have to put some kind of code like this :

```
_imagebutton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs eventsArgs) =>
    {
        View v = ...
        MvxBindableListView l = ...
        int p = l.GetPositionForView(...);
        l.PerformItemClick(..., p, p); 
     };
```

With this piece of code the right item is selected and the behaviour is correct (as long as I don't want to fire a real event with ItemClick).  But this solution is the "Android way" and not really crossplatform (and I let you imagine the dreadful code to initialize all that stuff)

Someone has a better solution?

Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partly, this feels like this is just 'UI eye candy' - and so falls within the domain of 'View concern' - and so it isn't something that mvvmcross normally tries to make cross platform.

However... I think there is a way.

If the command handler within the ViewModel, also sets a CurrentSelectedPosition integer on the ViewModel, then each UI can bind the SelectedItemPosition from ViewModel to each list in each ui - and this should cause the UI to natively update the selection.

I think that would work... But on Android it would need some binding :

```
public class MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemPositionTargetB-inging : MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private readonly AdapterView _adapterView;

    public MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemPositionTargetBinging(AdapterView adapterView)
    {
        _adapterView = adapterView;
        _adapterView.ItemSelected += AdapterViewOnItemSelected;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        _adapterView.SetSelection((int)value);
    }

    private void AdapterViewOnItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs itemSelectedEventArgs)
    {
        FireValueChanged(itemSelectedEventArgs.Position);
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get
        {
            return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay;
        }
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(Int32);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            if (_adapterView != null)
            {
                _adapterView.ItemSelected -= AdapterViewOnItemSelected;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
```

registered using:

```
        registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<AdapterView>("SelectedItemPosition", adapterView => new MvxAdapterViewSelectedItemPositionTargetBinging(adapterView)));
```

and bound to the UI in axml e.g. as:

```
<Mvx.MvxBindableListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Emails'},'SelectedItemPosition':{'Path':'CurrentSelectedPosition'}}"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_email"
/>
```

I tested this idea using an email list where the ViewModel list items were:

```
    public class SimpleEmail
    {
        public EmailViewModel Parent { get; set; }
        public string From { get; set; }    
        public string Header { get; set; }    
        public string Message { get; set; }    
        public ICommand Command1
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxRelayCommand(() => Parent.CurrentSelectedPosition = Parent.Emails.IndexOf(this));
            }
        }
    }
```

- but obviously this is just a demo...

---

Note: I'm using selected position rather than selected object in the code above - because I know the lists you are using are very long!

---

If you wanted to consider a different approach to your android-only code, then I think you can do that by inheriting from Mvx.MvxBindableListView (and possibly the list item too) and using those classes to update the selection in a possibly less painful way.

Comment: Hi Stuart,Thank you again for your fast answer.  It seems Android does not react on the _adapterView.SetSelection((int)value). That's why I did have to do a PeformItemClick on the ListView with the right position. Nevertheless, your solution is prettier because it's linked on the ListView natively.  I will try to inherit from the MvxBindableListView whenever I will have time (The deadline is coming fast!)

Comment: AdapterView seems to respond to SetSelection here - but maybe it depends on what your "visual selector" is. I think there is a difference between state_selected and state_pressed - but I'm not an expert on this!